# How do you bring up the CSS color picker in Visual Studio 2015 with a key combination?

Tags: css, visual-studio-2015, color-picker

I often have to perform some work on CSS files inside Visual Studio (version 2015). When I work with colors however, I have to choose a more 'custom' color so I find the color picker very handy. My problem is that I don't know a short way for bringing that color picker up.

The way I do it is to first give a temporary color, say 'black'. And then wait the yellow light bulb to pop-up and choose `Pick color from palette` option. Does anyone know a keyboard combination that can pop-up the color picker? I am also using ReSharper 10.0.1

Answer (score 1):

Any time ReSharper has suggestions, you can press alt+enter to list them, then clicking enter again will apply the first option.  To display the color picker using only the keyboard, make sure the caret is on the color in your code and press alt+enter, then enter again.